# Replace modern rgba() notation in Tailwind CSS to support legacy browsers

Tags: javascript, css, npm, build, tailwind-css

Contemporary versions of Tailwind CSS v3+ builds colours into rgb space-slash colour notation that isn't supported by a legacy browser (Safari 11) that my web app now needs to support.

e.g. `rgb(163 160 158 / var(--tw-bg-opacity)`

The problems are the space separators and the `/ opacity` syntax.

I couldn't find anything in the Tailwind CSS docs re: config or options on this. I have previously overcome this by adding on a regex perl opertation to replace these and build.

```
npm run build && perl -pi -w -e 's/rgba?\\(\\s*\\d+)(\\s*\\s*\\d+)(\\s*\\s*\\d+) \\//rgba($1,$2,$3,/g)' dist/assets/index.*.css
```

The CI/CD deployment does not like this, and I feel like this is not the right way to deal with this.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?
What would be a more elegant way to replace these?

I do not make use of background-opacity if that makes things easier.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use background-opacity, you can disable it by adding this option to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    backgroundOpacity: false,
  },
}
```

I found the source in Tailwind v2, which doesn't appear in the current version but still works on it (Tailwind v3): [docs](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity#disabling).

---

For example, for the `bg-red-400` utility:

```html
<div class="bg-red-400">Background</div>
```

The generated class would be:

```css
.bg-red-400 {
    background-color: #f87171;
}
```

Instead of:

```css
background-color: rgb(248 113 113 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WhehyJ7J7t?file=config)